# STDIN bar at the bottom

Tags: perl, stdin

I was wondering how I could make an STDIN bar at the bottom (Like an irc client has) of my terminal. I have all incoming IRC data showing up in terminal, but I'd like to be able to chat directly within the terminal. My wording may be making this a little confusing, but hopefully you get what I'm saying.

I would rather not use TK for this. Simply an always-waiting STDIN in the terminal.
Type, it'll store the message in a variable, then send it to IRC using $sock->print.

Answer (score 1):

For text-based UI, you should reach for curses/ncurses. The [Curses](http://search.cpan.org/~giraffed/Curses-1.28/Curses.pm) library is rather low-level, so you may prefer to use something like [Curses::Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/~dams/Curses-Toolkit-0.211/lib/Curses/Toolkit.pm)—specifically the [Curses::Toolkit::Widget::Entry](http://search.cpan.org/~dams/Curses-Toolkit-0.211/lib/Curses/Toolkit/Widget/Entry.pm) class seems to do what you want—or [Curses::UI](http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI-0.9609/lib/Curses/UI.pm). They may be overkill for your use case, but will scale well as you add more features to your client.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. I'm looking for the same thing IRSSI uses. Text scrolls, but has an input bar at the bottom.

Comment: @user2152679 yes, use curses to do that.